# CSS re-positioning of sections without absolute positioning

Tags: css

I have three sections all with 100% width;

```
<section>
    <h1>section 1</h1>
</section>
<section>
    <h1>section 2</h1>
</section>
<section>
    <h1>section 3</h1>
</section>
```

They are in this order because the page reads correctly like this.  However, for presentation purposes I would like the last section to be at the top and push the other two down.

I know I can position this absolutely and then the other sections accordingly, but I was wondering if there was a better solution to this that would allow the other two sections to be pushed down by the content in the last section.

I am also **not** after a JavaScript solution to this.

Comment: the only two ways of doing are the two ways you don't want to use. It can be done with one line of jQuery - assign a class to last and first section `$('.last').prependTo('.first');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to do that without either changing your HTML or using absolute positioning. You've set up the flow of the document to be a certain way (by putting your HTML in a certain way), therefore the only way you can change that flow without changing the HTML is to use a directive that takes the element out of the normal document flow (and the only two that do that are `absolute` and `fixed`).

Barring those two options, the only thing you have left is JavaScript, but even then, it would be reordering the HTML on the fly (putting your last one first). This can work, as long as the user agent that you're looking to support by putting it in the order you have doesn't use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Shauna, that is what I suspected.  I felt the document read better in a different order than the way it was presented, but I guess sometimes you have to compromise